# how to get the content of a variable from the last element

Tags: php, foreach, reverse

I was just wondering how I can get the content of a variable starting from the last value instead of the first ( using foreach),

```
 $variable = [1,2,3,4];
```

how can I print 4 then 3 and so on (if the size of the variable in unknown, is it possible to get the last value first).

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$last = array_shift(array_reverse($array, TRUE));
```

Or simply by

```
foreach (array_reverse($array) as $element) { ... }
```

Comment: Or the single function approach array_pop()

Comment: Yes it's quicker to obtain the last one really

Answer (score 2):

you can use [`array_reverse()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php). Some examples:

```
foreach (array_reverse($variable) as $num) {
    echo $num;
}

implode(',', array_reverse($variable));
```

Answer (score 0):

end() also works.